# No admin password set

Tags: password

I booted Ubuntu 12.10 32bit from pendive.

I would like to re-partition my hard drive using gparted, but it requires root privilege* that I could not provide, because there is no password set.

> (*) Root privileges are required for running gparted.

What can I do?

Comment: Is this a Live environment?

Comment: @LordofTime I don't know, but I think no.

Comment: @LordofTime Live session user - this one can I chose if I install something in Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Are you using the ubuntu@ubuntu user, or are you on some other user?

Answer (score 1):

How are you running gparted? You can run it by opening a terminal and typing

```
sudo gparted
```

this will run it as root/superuser without having to set a root password.

Comment: I get this:admin@ubuntu:~$ sudo gparted
[sudo] password for admin:

Comment: admin@ubuntu's not the ubuntu@ubuntu user.  the ubuntu@ubuntu user will have sudo.  how're you getting to admin@ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you have booted from and are using a Live CD or USB there should be no password.

I would suggest the following :

Try using `Disc Utility` instead of `Gparted`.

If that fails then you should download the [Ubuntu.iso](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) again or perhaps [Gparted Live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php), check the md5sum and create a new bootable CD / USB using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) maybe, then boot it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do exactly?

You can partition your HDD with the Ubuntu installer in any way that would be in the framework of a new Ubuntu installation e.g. the "something else" option when you're asked whether you want to replace existing OS or install alongside etc.

If you simply want to partition your harddrive for other purposes, Gparted Live might be a better option as it is more flexible.

Comment: he's in the live environment.

Comment: Sure and that's why I asked what he wants to do. Is he in the live environment in preparation for a hard install or does he wish to remain live and simply administer his HDD? I made suggestions for both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Live environment, then sudo will still work, the ubuntu user on the LiveUSB can use sudo.

The command for `gparted` (which is  already included in the Live environment) is:
`sudo gparted` in terminal, or alt+f2, then `gksudo gparted`.

Answer (score -2):

you should create a root password if it is a fresh install or have not been created yet. in a terminal -> sudo passwd root -> follow the instructions, define your new password then you can use that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Again, there is no reason to set a root password.